# Generate random number by odds

Tags: c, random

I would like to add to this random function a parameter which represent odds of returning true
for example rand_num(80)
will give 80% odds of returning true.

```
bool rand_num()             // randomize 0 or 1
{
int result =0;
srand(time(NULL));
result = (rand()%2);

return result;

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So two people have given similar answers that are simple mod. Both are wrong. Correct version:

```
bool randX(int X)
{
    do {
       int rnd = rand() & 127;
       if (rnd < X) return true;
       if (rnd >= X && rnd < 100) return false;
    } while (1);
}
```

Please note that using mod destabilizes as the distribution of rand() is not smooth over arbitrary mod.

Comment: +1 Joshua correctly warns about modulo bias - you should look into it

Comment: bit-and doesn't destabilize rand?

Comment: I think your return statements are the wrong way round. E.g. for `X = 10` your function seems to give a ~90% chance of returning true.

Comment: @Bloomfiled: Indeed. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

*(EDIT: It's been suggested that this answer is wrong because the modulo introduces a bias. In reality, if your application is sensitive enough to be affected by the bias, then you shouldn't be using `rand()` in the first place. This is based on statistical analysis rather than hypothetical conjecture.)*

Modulo your `rand()` output by 100, and if the result is less than or equal to the odds, return true.

As a side note, you're not really using `srand()` correctly. You should typically call it once at the start of your program, rather than every time you generate a random number.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/10396) for why this is biased:

Comment: The biasing issue is definitely a fair point. However, I'd argue that `rand()` is typically such a poor generator (in terms of uniformity) that the effect of bias will be trivial for most applications which are likely to use it.

Comment: Sorry I neglected that. I'm used to a fixed rand().

Answer (score 1):

```
bool randOdds(float odds) //odds should be a percentage between 0 and 1
{
   return ( rand()*(1.0/RAND_MAX) <= odds );
}
```

Comment: Well here's another way. I use a loop, you use the FPU. Choose your poison I guess.

Comment: This answer is provably non-uniform; it's basically a hash function mapping all possible values of `rand()` onto either `0` or `1`. Since there are `1<<X` possible values of `rand()`, and that's not divisible by 5, we *can't possibly* have exactly four-fifths of the possible values hash to `1`.

Comment: @Quuxplusone: True but it's never off by more than odds / RAND_MAX.

Comment: @Joshua Sure, and it takes a `float`, which could be a convenient API if you want something to happen with probability (roughly) `sqrt(0.5)`. (I'm not being sarcastic; floating point *is* nice sometimes.) But it has the exact same non-uniformity problem as the naive `rand() % 100 < 80` approach, for the OP's use-case. ...wait, aren't you the @Joshua who wrote the "beware of non-uniformity" answer above? :D